# Power Query: Split table column with multiple cells in the same row

Tags: excel, powerquery, sharepoint-list

I have a SharePoint list as a datasource in Power Query.

It has a "AttachmentFiles" column, that is a table, in that table i want the values from the column "ServerRelativeURL".

[image]

I want to split that column so each value in "ServerRelativeURL"gets its own column.

[image]

I can get the values if i use the expand table function, but it will split it into multiple rows, I want to keep it in one row.

[image]

I only want one row per unique ID.

Example:

[image]

I can live with a fixed number of columns as there are usually no more than 3 attachments per ID.

I'm thinking that I can add a custom column that refers to "AttachmentFiles ServerRelativeURL Value(1)" but I don't know how.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manged to solve it myself.

I added 3 custom columns like this
CustomColumn1: `[AttachmentFiles]{0}`
CustomColumn2: `[AttachmentFiles]{1}`
CustomColumn3: `[AttachmentFiles]{2}`

And expanded them with only the "ServerRelativeURL" selected.
It would be nice to have a dynamic solution. But this will work fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
let
    fn = (x)=> {x, #table({"ServerRelativeUrl"},List.FirstN(List.Zip({{"a".."z"}}), x*2))},
    Source = #table({"id", "AttachmentFiles"},{fn(2),fn(3),fn(1)}),
    replace = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,0,0,(a,b,c)=>a[ServerRelativeUrl],{"AttachmentFiles"}),
    cols = List.Transform({1..List.Max(List.Transform(replace[AttachmentFiles], List.Count))}, each "url"&Text.From(_)),
    split = Table.SplitColumn(replace, "AttachmentFiles", (x)=>List.Transform({0..List.Count(x)-1}, each x{_}), cols)
in
    split
```

[image]

Comment: If I add a custom column with that code. It adds a new column with a table. In that table i get the same as the picture you pasted. But none of the values from the "Attachment Files" table.

Comment: You shouldn't add custom column. You should copy last 3 steps (replace, cols, split) from my code to yours (in Advanced Editor). Of course, you should specify name of your last step instead of Source in replace step. Just in case - after in expression should be the last step's name, i.e. split.

Comment: I tried, but I think it's a above my level. I will go with my own solution, but thanks for the help.